# moving through a grid nullpointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to allow movement through a grid and display my current location with a string. I move in increments of one therefore if I am on a1 and type 'down' I will be on b1.

```
public class ClassMethodtest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    Scanner replay = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String answer;
    
   
    
   do{ 
      MoveClass newMoveClass = new MoveClass();
   
     newMoveClass.MoveAround();
   
     newMoveClass.Location();
   
            System.out.println("move again?");
   
    answer = replay.next();
   
   
   } while(answer.equals("yes"));
}




public class MoveClass {

private final String array[] = {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", 
                         "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"};
private final Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    

private String location; 


public void MoveAround(){
    
    System.out.println("move");
    String answer = kb.next();

   switch (location) {
       case "A1":
           if(answer.equals("down")){
               location = array[4];
           }
           else if(answer.equals("right")){
               location = array[1];
           }  break;
           //etc.....
```

Why does this code throw a null pointer exception?

Answer (score 2):

```
private String location;
```

location is null. you need set init location like:

```
private String location = array[6];
```

Comment: Oh right. I did that in the first place but my location wasn't saved and reverted back to what I had put for the location array initially.